# Global Variable typescript/ javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to declare a global variable with default value

```
const Months = [
{ name: 'January' },
{ name: 'February' },
{ name: 'March' },
{ name: 'April' },
{ name: 'May' },
{ name: 'June' },
{ name: 'July' },
{ name: 'August' },
{ name: 'September' },
{ name: 'October' },
{ name: 'November' },
{ name: 'December' }
];
```

and i want to use the Months Variable in multiple files. without redeclaring it again.
file1.tsx
Months.map(x => x.name);

file2.tsx
Months.map(x => x.name);

how im going to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoiding global variables can help to reduce bugs in your program and make your code easier to understand.

> and i want to use the Months Variable in multiple files. without redeclaring it again.

This is exactly what is addressed by [JavaScript modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules), using the `export` and `import` keywords:

`./constants.ts`:

```ts
export const months = [
  { name: 'January' },
  { name: 'February' },
  { name: 'March' },
  { name: 'April' },
  { name: 'May' },
  { name: 'June' },
  { name: 'July' },
  { name: 'August' },
  { name: 'September' },
  { name: 'October' },
  { name: 'November' },
  { name: 'December' },
] as const;
```

`./another_module.ts`:

```ts
import { months } from './constants.js';

console.log(months.map(obj => obj.name)); // ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
```

Answer (score -1):

add this code to your run file (I think it's called `main.ts` )

```
window.Months = [
{ name: 'January' },
{ name: 'February' },
{ name: 'March' },
{ name: 'April' },
{ name: 'May' },
{ name: 'June' },
{ name: 'July' },
{ name: 'August' },
{ name: 'September' },
{ name: 'October' },
{ name: 'November' },
{ name: 'December' }
];
```

and `global.d.ts`

```
declare var Months: { name: string }[]
```